# how to get the url after redirection using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a project of web crawler and right now i am facing a problem .

How to get the url after redirection of a page ??

I tried requests and it returns the value `<Response [200]>`

When i am crawling the download link of a file such as this one http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/download/f28dbaab19e38f3239d69ed7c350ac5d/ it opens a page where it is written program is downloading but after few seconds the program starts download... i want the url of the download

thanks in advance..

Comment: Which url are you trying to get?

Comment: i am facing problem when i am crawling through the sites like filehippo

Comment: I know haha, but what is the problem exactly? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Are you wanting to retrieve the content of a page after a request is made?

Comment: Question is incomplete.

Comment: when i am crawling the download link of a file such as this one http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/download/f28dbaab19e38f3239d69ed7c350ac5d/ i opens a page where it is written program is downloading but after few seconds the program starts download... i want the url of the download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to download the file directly is located in the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3; url=/download/file/0d48d61bb8c894b7388e83a3c873cde48f0b2cc330872f5ce77a3b38b24a4942/"/>
```

You need to read that link from the file, and then request it. Once you do, it will then direct you to the actual file download link:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://fs41.filehippo.com/9452/f9851528b9974e08bf9fa217a7daa049/Firefox Setup 43.0.3.exe [following]
```

For requests; it will handle this redirection automatically for you; and the end result is you can then start downloading the file.

Comment: really you are a genius wish i can hit more upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

### Your download is initiated only after some code is ran on the browser

It doesn't seem that your example URL redirects using an HTTP redirection, it seems to initiate a download once the browser finds that page and some client side code is executed. Your URL isn't an HTTP redirect.

To understand what I'm saying open the development console (FireBug, Chrome console etc) on your browser in its Network tab and refresh the page see all that happens before the actual file is downloaded by your browser. In the network tab you can get the URL to the file too.

However it may be not be useful to crawl because the URL may be "salted" with a token that expires or is only valid for the client that crawled it, basically rendering that download URL unshareable.

### Browser automation

You might be able to that URL with some browser automation like Selenium or PhantomJS, by watchng the networks log and grepping for the URL structures you want (e.g. for this file you're looking for a `.exe` in the URL)

Bottom line is: **you *can* get that URL, by using a browser automation tool and capturing all its network data, however a secure architecture would render that URL unshareable.**

### A URL that does actually redirect

However I'll give you an example that does redirect to show you how to do it for an URL that actually redirects with HTTP, with the [Python requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Your URL doesn't redirect

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/download/f28dbaab19e38f3239d69ed7c350ac5d/')
>>> response.history
[]  # There's no redirect there
>>> response.status_code
200
```

Let's try with a test URL that redirects

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/redirect/3')
>>> response.history
[<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>]
>>> for r in response.history: print r.status_code, r.url
... 
302 http://httpbin.org/redirect/3
302 http://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/2
302 http://httpbin.org/relative-redirect/1
>>>
```

Comment: ok my url doesn't redirect i accept but there is no download links in the source code of that page why ??

Comment: and how can i get that download link

Comment: Because in a system that doesn't want people to easily find out the URLs and share them, you won't embed those in the source code of the page, you'd return it to the page on an individual basis from the server to the page, then the page initiates the download on the browser. That returned URL can also be made to only be valid for a given time, client identified with a token, making it very hard to share. I've updated my answer with tools to study this some more, like Selenium and PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `geturl()`
or 
to get the current url use

```
self.request.url
```